# Moodle local_plugin setting to select multiple user

Tags: php, moodle

Hi everyone I am writing a local plugin where I need to give access of the result is to some specific users. So I created a simple setting page and able to retrieve all the user list along with the id and username
If I am using configmulti_select
its working fine
all users are visible and I am able to select multiple user but problem is in production users list can be much larger so it can give trouble to finding the username in the list

I saw one more setting

```
admin_setting_configselect_autocomplete()
```

but when I am using this all my users are visible but it allows me to get only one user . I want multiple users how can select multiple users
I tried to search for settings but no such setting

`admin_setting_configmulti_select_autocomplete`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would be far easier to create a permission and use capabilities

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/subsystems/access

In `/local/mypluginname/db/access.php` have something like this

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$capabilities = array(

    'local/mypluginname:mypermission' => array(
        'riskbitmask' => RISK_PERSONAL,
        'captype' => 'write',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
        ),
    ),
```

In `/local/mypluginname/lang/en/local_mypluginname.php`

```
$string['mypluginname:mypermission'] = 'Ability to something something mypermission';
```

You will probably need to bump the version of local plugin to install the capability

Then in your code use something like

```
require_capability('local/mypluginname:mypermission', $context);
```

or

```
if (has_capability('local/mypluginname:mypermission', $context)) {
    // Do something
}
```

You can use the `archetypes` element to automatically assign the permission to core roles

Or assign the permission manually via Site admin > users > permissions > define roles > [select role] > edit role > [filter for `mypermission`]

Comment: Thank you Russell for your reply but problem is 
This will go to all teacher like if I am giving capability to the a role so all user's having that role will be able to see this but problem is I don't want that, my main concern is
for example total number of teachers 7 but I want only 3 teachers to give permission so how I can get that?

Comment: Just create another role :) Add the new permission to it. Then assign the role to the required teachers. https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Creating_custom_roles

Comment: Actually this is one good idea but trouble is also I need to distribute the copy of the plugin to some educational institute so they will need to do this stuff manually, I was thinking if somehow they don't need to do anything but if nothing else will wokr I will go with this idea